# Trying to change color on event, color won't change reliably

Tags: javascript

In the code below, I want the color of the cells on mouseover to change according to the button pressed.

However, when I click on a color button it changes once and then works maybe sometimes if I click a weird combination of colors.

For example, I can click blue, then red, green, yellow and it works as intended. If I want to change to green it doesn't change at all. But sometimes it works if I want to change to blue. Why does this happen?

```js
function drawPictureBlue(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3500D3';

}

function drawPictureRed(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

}

function drawPictureGreen(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

}

function drawPictureYellow(e) {
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

}

const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');

const blueColor = document.querySelector('.blue')
const redColor = document.querySelector('.red');
const greenColor = document.querySelector('.green');
const yellowColor = document.querySelector('.yellow');

//cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureDefault));

blueColor.addEventListener('click', function() {

  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureBlue));
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.removeEventListener('mouseover',
    drawPictureRed, drawPictureGreen, drawPictureYellow));
})
redColor.addEventListener('click', function() {

  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureRed));
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.removeEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureBlue,
    drawPictureGreen, drawPictureYellow));
})
greenColor.addEventListener('click', function() {

  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureGreen));
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.removeEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureBlue,
    drawPictureRed, drawPictureYellow));
})
yellowColor.addEventListener('click', function() {

  cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureYellow));
  cells.forEach(cell => cell.removeEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureBlue,
    drawPictureRed, drawPictureGreen));
})
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id='header'></div>
  <div id='box'>
    <div id='btnArea'>
      <button class='clearBtn'></button>
    </div>
    <div id='container'></div>
    <div id='optionsArea'>
      <div class='options'></div>
      <button class='blue'>Blue</button>
      <button class='red'>Red</button>
      <button class='green'>Green</button>
      <button class='yellow'>Yellow</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: Please create [mre] with all relevant code. Use <> button in editor to create snippet.

Comment: use `cell.onmouseover = function() { ...` to overwrite then anytime you update it

Comment: the weird combination of colors is probably because of the fact that you can't remove multiple listeners with one `removeEventListener`

Comment: and replace `const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');` with `const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cell')];` because it does not have a `.forEach()`

Comment: @Antoni thank you, using the on mouseover function solved the issue. I don't have to remove the event listeners now either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read my comments

```
function drawPictureBlue(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#3500D3';
    
}
function drawPictureRed(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    
}
function drawPictureGreen(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    
}
function drawPictureYellow(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    
}

const cells = [...document.querySelectorAll('.cell')];

const blueColor = document.querySelector('.blue')
const redColor = document.querySelector('.red');
const greenColor = document.querySelector('.green');
const yellowColor = document.querySelector('.yellow');

//cells.forEach(cell => cell.addEventListener('mouseover', drawPictureDefault));

blueColor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.mouseover=drawPictureBlue);
})
redColor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.mouseover=drawPictureRed);
})
greenColor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.mouseover=drawPictureGreen);
})
yellowColor.addEventListener('click', function() {
    
    cells.forEach(cell => cell.mouseover=drawPictureYellow);
})
```

Comment: can you accept it then? (green checkmark)     :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't see the html part of your code, but if I would have to guess - the reason why some times it doesn't work is because you are not clicking on the desired element that you want to change.

try using `e.target.closest(<selector to change color>).style ..`
and it may solve the problem

Comment: I added the html above, and I tried your solution but it doesn't work